# How to configure the JS runtime at best?

Tags: spidermonkey

I wondering how to configure the JSRuntime at best.
There are many parameters for JS_NewRuntime(), JS_NewContext(), JS_SetGCParameter(), JS_SetGCParameterForThread(), ...
Are there some guidelines or recommendations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default options should work fine, I would just make sure that the method JIT is enabled -- this is done through a JS_SetOption that depends on which SpiderMonkey version you're running.

Also check out the [JSAPI user guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSAPI_User_Guide#A_minimal_example) for example embedding techniques and background information, as well as the [JSPI cookbook](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SpiderMonkey/JSAPI_Cookbook).